# Is my disk gone?

Tags: hardware, dmesg

My linux workstation just recently crashed. It now boots into a login screen and from there, if I log in, it logs me back out. Also, the resolution is much lower than it used to be. I think that it has something to do with the `ata9` device. Here is `dmesg | grep ata9`. Is there hope for this drive?

```
[   10.115435] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[   10.699688] ata9.00: ATA-8: WDC WD20EARS-00MVWB0, 51.0AB51, max UDMA/133
[   10.699692] ata9.00: 3907029168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32)
[   10.703725] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   10.719518] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[   41.946969] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: cmd error handler
[   41.947059] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[   41.947063] ata9.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x4 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[   41.947119] ata9.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[   41.947159] ata9.00: cmd 60/08:00:00:20:f2/00:00:e7:00:00/40 tag 2 ncq 4096 in
[   41.947220] ata9.00: status: { DRDY }
[   41.947241] ata9: hard resetting link
[   42.614055] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   42.614059] ata9.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[   42.614064] ata9: EH complete
[   72.986933] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: cmd error handler
[   72.986978] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[   72.986981] ata9.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x8 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[   72.987033] ata9.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[   72.987072] ata9.00: cmd 60/08:00:00:20:f2/00:00:e7:00:00/40 tag 3 ncq 4096 in
[   72.987132] ata9.00: status: { DRDY }
[   72.987151] ata9: hard resetting link
[   73.650031] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   73.650035] ata9.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[   73.650040] ata9: EH complete
[  104.026914] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: cmd error handler
[  104.026960] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[  104.026963] ata9.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x10 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[  104.027014] ata9.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  104.027053] ata9.00: cmd 60/08:00:00:20:f2/00:00:e7:00:00/40 tag 4 ncq 4096 in
[  104.027114] ata9.00: status: { DRDY }
[  104.027133] ata9: hard resetting link
[  104.685932] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  104.685936] ata9.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[  104.685940] ata9: EH complete
[  135.002901] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: cmd error handler
[  135.002948] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[  135.002964] ata9.00: NCQ disabled due to excessive errors
[  135.002966] ata9.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x20 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[  135.003007] ata9.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  135.003035] ata9.00: cmd 60/08:00:00:20:f2/00:00:e7:00:00/40 tag 5 ncq 4096 in
[  135.003109] ata9.00: status: { DRDY }
[  135.003128] ata9: hard resetting link
[  135.658058] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  135.658062] ata9.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[  135.658067] ata9: EH complete
[  139.490899] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: cmd error handler
[  139.490943] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[  139.490946] ata9.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  139.490994] ata9.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[  139.491033] ata9.00: cmd 25/00:08:00:20:f2/00:00:e7:00:00/e0 tag 6 dma 4096 in
[  139.491095] ata9.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  139.491114] ata9.00: error: { UNC }
[  139.499195] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  139.499288] ata9: EH complete
[  142.946887] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: cmd error handler
[  142.946932] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[  142.946935] ata9.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  142.946988] ata9.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[  142.947027] ata9.00: cmd 25/00:08:f0:1f:f2/00:00:e7:00:00/e0 tag 24 dma 4096 in
[  142.947090] ata9.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  142.947110] ata9.00: error: { UNC }
[  142.955997] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  142.956066] ata9: EH complete
[  146.198889] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: cmd error handler
[  146.198936] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[  146.198939] ata9.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  146.198986] ata9.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[  146.199022] ata9.00: cmd 25/00:08:00:20:f2/00:00:e7:00:00/e0 tag 26 dma 4096 in
[  146.199086] ata9.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  146.199105] ata9.00: error: { UNC }
[  146.207504] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  146.207562] ata9: EH complete
[  149.474887] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: cmd error handler
[  149.474931] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[  149.474934] ata9.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  149.474981] ata9.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[  149.475018] ata9.00: cmd 25/00:08:08:20:f2/00:00:e7:00:00/e0 tag 13 dma 4096 in
[  149.475080] ata9.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  149.475100] ata9.00: error: { UNC }
[  149.483122] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  149.483180] ata9: EH complete
[  152.726888] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: cmd error handler
[  152.726932] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[  152.726936] ata9.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  152.726982] ata9.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[  152.727019] ata9.00: cmd 25/00:08:08:20:f2/00:00:e7:00:00/e0 tag 21 dma 4096 in
[  152.727081] ata9.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  152.727100] ata9.00: error: { UNC }
[  152.735722] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  152.735812] ata9: EH complete
[  155.878889] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: cmd error handler
[  155.878931] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[  155.878934] ata9.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  155.878981] ata9.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[  155.879018] ata9.00: cmd 25/00:08:f8:1e:f2/00:00:e7:00:00/e0 tag 28 dma 4096 in
[  155.879080] ata9.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  155.879100] ata9.00: error: { UNC }
[  155.887138] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  155.887196] ata9: EH complete
[  159.134882] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: cmd error handler
[  159.134971] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[  159.134974] ata9.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  159.135008] ata9.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[  159.135033] ata9.00: cmd 25/00:08:f8:1e:f2/00:00:e7:00:00/e0 tag 5 dma 4096 in
[  159.135094] ata9.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  159.135113] ata9.00: error: { UNC }
[  159.143752] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  159.143843] ata9: EH complete
[  162.398896] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: cmd error handler
[  162.398943] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[  162.398959] ata9.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  162.398962] ata9.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[  162.398966] ata9.00: cmd 25/00:20:00:20:f2/00:00:e7:00:00/e0 tag 6 dma 16384 in
[  162.398972] ata9.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  162.398973] ata9.00: error: { UNC }
[  162.407261] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  162.407300] ata9: EH complete
[  165.650874] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: cmd error handler
[  165.650918] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[  165.650921] ata9.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  165.650923] ata9.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[  165.650927] ata9.00: cmd 25/00:08:00:20:f2/00:00:e7:00:00/e0 tag 7 dma 4096 in
[  165.650941] ata9.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  165.650943] ata9.00: error: { UNC }
[  165.658889] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  165.658919] ata9: EH complete
[  168.786892] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: cmd error handler
[  168.786935] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[  168.786938] ata9.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  168.786941] ata9.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[  168.786957] ata9.00: cmd 25/00:08:f8:1e:f2/00:00:e7:00:00/e0 tag 14 dma 4096 in
[  168.786960] ata9.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  168.786961] ata9.00: error: { UNC }
[  168.795275] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  168.795302] ata9: EH complete
[  172.046889] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: cmd error handler
[  172.046934] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[  172.046936] ata9.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  172.046939] ata9.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[  172.046955] ata9.00: cmd 25/00:08:f8:1e:f2/00:00:e7:00:00/e0 tag 15 dma 4096 in
[  172.046957] ata9.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  172.046958] ata9.00: error: { AMNF }
[  172.054882] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  172.054911] ata9: EH complete
[  177.590873] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: cmd error handler
[  177.590920] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[  177.590923] ata9.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  177.590940] ata9.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[  177.590944] ata9.00: cmd 25/00:20:00:20:f2/00:00:e7:00:00/e0 tag 15 dma 16384 in
[  177.590949] ata9.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  177.590951] ata9.00: error: { UNC }
[  177.599078] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  177.599110] ata9: EH complete
[  180.866889] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: cmd error handler
[  180.866939] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[  180.866942] ata9.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  180.866944] ata9.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[  180.866948] ata9.00: cmd 25/00:08:00:20:f2/00:00:e7:00:00/e0 tag 16 dma 4096 in
[  180.866963] ata9.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  180.866964] ata9.00: error: { UNC }
[  180.874708] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  180.874736] ata9: EH complete
[  186.114870] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: cmd error handler
[  186.114913] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[  186.114917] ata9.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  186.114920] ata9.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[  186.114937] ata9.00: cmd 25/00:08:00:20:f2/00:00:e7:00:00/e0 tag 21 dma 4096 in
[  186.114939] ata9.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  186.114941] ata9.00: error: { UNC }
[  186.123209] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  186.123258] ata9: EH complete
[  189.366811] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: cmd error handler
[  189.366864] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[  189.366867] ata9.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  189.366870] ata9.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[  189.366874] ata9.00: cmd 25/00:08:00:20:f2/00:00:e7:00:00/e0 tag 26 dma 4096 in
[  189.366876] ata9.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  189.366877] ata9.00: error: { UNC }
[  189.374864] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  189.374893] ata9: EH complete
[  192.994864] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: cmd error handler
[  192.994908] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[  192.994911] ata9.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  192.994913] ata9.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[  192.994930] ata9.00: cmd 25/00:08:f8:1e:f2/00:00:e7:00:00/e0 tag 2 dma 4096 in
[  192.994932] ata9.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  192.994933] ata9.00: error: { UNC }
[  193.003447] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  193.003493] ata9: EH complete
[  196.250857] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: cmd error handler
[  196.250899] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[  196.250901] ata9.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  196.250904] ata9.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[  196.250920] ata9.00: cmd 25/00:08:f8:1e:f2/00:00:e7:00:00/e0 tag 3 dma 4096 in
[  196.250922] ata9.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  196.250924] ata9.00: error: { UNC }
[  196.259506] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  196.259535] ata9: EH complete
[  200.059683] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: cmd error handler
[  200.059700] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[  203.334864] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: cmd error handler
[  203.334913] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[  203.334917] ata9.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  203.334920] ata9.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[  203.334925] ata9.00: cmd 25/00:08:00:20:f2/00:00:e7:00:00/e0 tag 15 dma 4096 in
[  203.334930] ata9.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  203.334932] ata9.00: error: { UNC }
[  203.343152] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  203.343185] ata9: EH complete
[  206.586868] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: cmd error handler
[  206.586912] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[  206.586916] ata9.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  206.586918] ata9.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[  206.586922] ata9.00: cmd 25/00:08:00:20:f2/00:00:e7:00:00/e0 tag 21 dma 4096 in
[  206.586924] ata9.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  206.586938] ata9.00: error: { UNC }
[  206.594757] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  206.594788] ata9: EH complete
[  209.570859] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: cmd error handler
[  209.570903] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[  209.570906] ata9.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  209.570909] ata9.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[  209.570925] ata9.00: cmd 25/00:08:f8:1e:f2/00:00:e7:00:00/e0 tag 2 dma 4096 in
[  209.570927] ata9.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  209.570928] ata9.00: error: { UNC }
[  209.579027] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  209.579056] ata9: EH complete
[  212.826800] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: cmd error handler
[  212.826850] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[  212.826856] ata9.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  212.826861] ata9.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[  212.826867] ata9.00: cmd 25/00:08:f8:1e:f2/00:00:e7:00:00/e0 tag 6 dma 4096 in
[  212.826869] ata9.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  212.826871] ata9.00: error: { UNC }
[  212.835676] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  212.835707] ata9: EH complete
[  216.078856] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: cmd error handler
[  216.078899] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[  216.078902] ata9.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  216.078905] ata9.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[  216.078921] ata9.00: cmd 25/00:08:00:20:f2/00:00:e7:00:00/e0 tag 8 dma 4096 in
[  216.078923] ata9.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  216.078925] ata9.00: error: { UNC }
[  216.087168] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  216.087199] ata9: EH complete
[  219.334861] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: cmd error handler
[  219.334906] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[  219.334909] ata9.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  219.334911] ata9.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[  219.334915] ata9.00: cmd 25/00:08:08:20:f2/00:00:e7:00:00/e0 tag 9 dma 4096 in
[  219.334930] ata9.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  219.334931] ata9.00: error: { UNC }
[  219.343821] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  219.343848] ata9: EH complete
[  222.586852] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: cmd error handler
[  222.586925] sas: ata9: end_device-0:1: dev error handler
[  222.586931] ata9.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  222.586936] ata9.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[  222.586944] ata9.00: cmd 25/00:08:00:20:f2/00:00:e7:00:00/e0 tag 10 dma 4096 in
[  222.586960] ata9.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  222.586961] ata9.00: error: { UNC }
[  222.595309] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  222.595337] ata9: EH complete
```

Comment: Yep, it's dead. [Go here and RMA it.](http://support.wdc.com/Warranty/warrantyStatus.aspx).

Comment: Also check the cable and try it on a different computer. It may not necessarily be a fault of your disk.